# C++ регулярное выражение

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, почему код:

```
regex wrong("[a-z]{4,}");
string s="hYhghgZ";
if(regex_match(s, wrong)) cout << "wrong " << endl;
else cout << "ok";
```

выдает `ok`, хотя в строке `hYhghgZ` есть подходящий фрагмент "hghg"?

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в результате? Только проверить на частичное совпадение или получить весь массив совпадений? Также см. [Разницу между `std::regex_match` и `std::regex_search`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696250/difference-between-stdregex-match-stdregex-search) (англ.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это все потому, что `regex_match()` - ищет полное совпадение строк. Он не ищет шаблон в части строки. Для поиска подстроки используйте `regex_search()`.

На [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) честно пишут:

> Note that regex_match will only successfully match a regular
>   expression to an entire character sequence, whereas std::regex_search
>   will successfully match subsequences.